# Pass Arraylist String using intent over 2 activities

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-intent

I have 3 activities, activity 1 is fetching data from firebase, activity 2 is splash screen and activity 3 is show the data. I want to pass the data from activity 1 to activity 3 using intent. but it doesnt work. If i dont use activity 2 it works, but i want to use activity 2 as well.

Activity 1 fetching data from firebase

```
matchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            mkomref = mDbref.child("Students");
            string = matchKriteria.getText().toString();
            Query query = mkomp.orderByChild("Komp").equalTo(string);
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        if(nameList.size()>0)
                            nameList.clear();

                        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            nameList.add(data.child("Name").getValue(String.class));
                        }
                        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, LoadingActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("value",nameList);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
```

Activity 2 splash screen

```
public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT= 5000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);


new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent =new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
},SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

Activity 3 show the result

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private ArrayList<String> nameList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bedrift_match_resultat);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (intent != null)
        nameList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("value");

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    if (nameList.size() > 0) {
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, nameList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo It crashed when it comes to the third activity

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo Answered below, thanks

Comment: Accepted answer notes that the author forgot to send/retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it didn't work because, in your LoadingActivity you didn’t retrieve data from FirstActivity and you’re not sending it to ResultActivity. So, your namelist in ResultActivity is null

You can try this:

```
public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT= 5000;
private ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
    if (getIntent() != null) {
        namelist.addAll(getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("value");
    }


new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent =new Intent(LoadingActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("value",nameList);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
},SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```